# SQL query: Number of comments posted in last 24 hours by people a user is following

Tags: php, sql, drupal

I've got a site where users follow users they like and can read their latest updates.

I'd like to show my users a simple count of how many comments the people they follow have posted in the last 24 hours.  I'm having trouble figuring out the query.

I have two tables.

comment

- cid (comment id)
- timestamp
- uid (id of person who posted the comment)
- comment (content of the comment)

user_relationships

- requester_id (id of the user who followed the person)
- requestee_id (id of the person who was followed)

In plain english, I think the query is something like this:

COUNT the cid.comment from the comments table where uid.comment is equal to requestee_id.user_relationships associated with  requester_id.user_relationships value of X.

I need to get all the UIDs of people being followed by a given UID from the usr_relationship table.  Then count up how many comments those people have posted in the last 24 hours and spit that number out.

What would this query look like?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM user_relationships ur 
JOIN comment c ON (ur.requestee_id = c.uid)
WHERE c.timestamp >= (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - <interval of 1day>) 
  AND ur.requester_id = <visitor>
```

Also hope this helps.

You'll have to figure out how to create an interval to subtract from the timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM Comment
     WHERE uid in (SELECT user_relationships.requesterid
                     FROM user_relationships
                    WHERE user_relationships.requesteeid = @ThisID)
```

Hope this helps,
Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

using a join

```
SELECT
    COUNT(c.cid)
FROM
    user_relationships r
    INNER JOIN comments c ON c.uid=r.requester_id AND c.timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR
WHERE
    r.requestee_id={user_id}
```

Answer (score 0):

join is faster

```
SELECT COUNT(comments.uid) FROM comments JOIN user_relationships ON user_relationships.requestee_id = comments.uid WHERE user_relationships.requester_id = $some_id
```